# Android Studio retrieve information from XML in a override method

Tags: java, android, xml

Sorry for the noob question but I did not come across any situations that would work for me. Im sure this is super simple, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Objective:
I want to be able to take the name of what the user specified and add it to the markers title.

What I know:
I am unable to inflate the xml and grab it via that way cause the method is being override and if I inflate to my knowledge will no longer allow me to override the method. How should I approach this?

MapsAcitivy

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, addPlace.Communicator {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    int mStackLevel;
    int YES_NO_CALL;
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final Context context = this;

    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;

    ClusterManager<ClusterRequest> mClusterManager;


    class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        // These are both viewgroups containing an ImageView with id "badge" and two TextViews with id
        // "title" and "snippet".
        private final View mWindow;

        //private final View mContents;

        CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
            mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
            //mContents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            render(marker, mWindow);
            return mWindow;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
            TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

            // Setting the latitude
            tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

            // Setting the longitude
            tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);

            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;
            //render(marker, mContents);
            //return mContents;
        }

        private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(23)
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager initialLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String initialProvider = initialLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location initialLocation = initialLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(initialProvider);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            double initialLatitude = initialLocation.getLatitude();
            double initialLongitude = initialLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng initialLatLng = new LatLng(initialLatitude, initialLongitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(initialLatLng, 14.9f));
            //mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterRequest>(getApplicationContext(), mMap);
            mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view){
        //do something when button is clicked.
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_place);
        dialog.setTitle("Add Place");

        Button btnLogin = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addPlacebtnSubmit);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        final EditText txtUsername = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtStopName);

        // Attached listener for add place GUI button
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String stopName = txtUsername.getText().toString();
                if(stopName.length() > 4){
                    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // Should we show an explanation?
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                        } else {

                            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                            // MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
                            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                            // result of the request.
                        }
                    }
                    LocationManager currentLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Criteria currentCriteria = new Criteria();
                    String currentProvider = currentLocationManager.getBestProvider(currentCriteria, true);
                    Location currentLocation = currentLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(currentProvider);
                    double currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                    double currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

                    ClusterRequest testCluster = new ClusterRequest(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
                    mClusterManager.addItem(testCluster);
                    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MapIconRender(getApplicationContext(), mMap, mClusterManager));

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
                else{
                    txtUsername.setError("Stop name must be at least 5 characters long.");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

MapIconRender.java

```
public class MapIconRender extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterRequest> {

        public MapIconRender(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                             ClusterManager<ClusterRequest> clusterManager) {
            super(context, map, clusterManager);
        }

            @Override
            protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered (ClusterRequest item, MarkerOptions
            markerOptions){
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_outside_azure));
                markerOptions.snippet("Status: ");
                markerOptions.title(stopName); //<------ THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE STOP NAME TO BE WHAT THE USER ENTERED.
                super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
            }
}
```

add_place.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#fff" android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/HorizontalLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#aaa" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/name" />
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtStopName"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Name of this stop (5-100 characters)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Type:"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/type" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/type_prompt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/HorizontalLine2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#aaa" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel" android:text="Cancel"
            android:onClick="addPlaceCancel"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/addPlacebtnSubmit" android:text="Submit"
            android:onClick="addPlaceSubmit"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ClusterRequest.java

```
public class ClusterRequest implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;

public ClusterRequest(double lat, double lng) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SuhyeonLee Not sure if this is what you meant (please let me know) but I did find the answer surprisingly enough in the demo that google released for their customize cluster demo. Heres what I learned. When calling the MapIconRender.java class via

`mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MapIconRender(getApplicationContext(), mMap, mClusterManager));`

Which will run this method in the MapIconRender.java class

```
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered (ClusterRequest item, MarkerOptions
            markerOptions)
```

Which means whatever variables in the ClusterRequest class will be accessible here in the MapIconRender.java class and can be accessed via (item.variableName). I apologize for not posting the code for the file ClusterRequest, I didnt think it was needed. ill go back and add that snippet to my original question.

Anyway the new code I needed to add was as follows:

In the MapsActivity class I needed to pass the ClusterRequest class the name of the marker(or title of the marker) via:

`ClusterRequest testCluster = new ClusterRequest(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, stopName); //stopName was added here.`

And in the ClusterRequest class I needed to add the "global variable" of the marker name (aka stopName) via:

```
public class ClusterRequest implements ClusterItem {
private final LatLng mPosition;
public final String stopName; //Add a "global variable" here so it can be accessible in the MapIconRender class.

public ClusterRequest(double lat, double lng, String _stopName) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    stopName = _stopName;
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
  }
}
```

And finally in my MapIconRender.java class I can add the title name of the marker via:

```
public class MapIconRender extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterRequest> {

        public MapIconRender(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                             ClusterManager<ClusterRequest> clusterManager) {
            super(context, map, clusterManager);
        }

            @Override
            protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered (ClusterRequest item, MarkerOptions
            markerOptions){
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_outside_azure));
                markerOptions.snippet("Status: ");
                markerOptions.title("Title: " + item.stopName); //Now we can access the title of the marker by calling item.variableName
                super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
            }
}
```

Im really sorry about the noob question here but I hope this helps someone out that may have the same question as I did and thank you for your answers! "SO" community is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you override `onClusterItemRendered()` method?

I think you can save your marker name in `onBeforeClusterItemRendered()` to any class-global variable String, and set the marker name in `onClusterItemRendered()` with `Marker.setTitle(yourSavedTitle);` or something.

Something like this:

```
public class MapIconRender extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterRequest> {
    private String mMarkerTitle;

    public MapIconRender(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                         ClusterManager<ClusterRequest> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered (ClusterRequest item, MarkerOptions
        markerOptions){
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_outside_azure));
            markerOptions.snippet("Status: ");
            markerOptions.title(stopName); //<------ THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE STOP NAME TO BE WHAT THE USER ENTERED.
            mMarkerTitle = stopName;
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered (ClusterRequest item, Marker marker){
            marker.setTitle(mMarkerTitle);
        }
}
```

Comment: Huh im not quite sure im picking up on what your saying, can you please provide an example? If im thinking about this correctly it wouldnt solve my issue (I defiantly could be wrong here). But I think cause im still not pulling the titles name from the user's input from the add_place.xml, it would all just be local variables to the class and not reaching out the xml for the value. Again I could be wrong but if you provide an example i'll know more or less of what your explaining. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE EFFORT IN RESPONDING!